# jquery template plugin function scope within a class

Tags: jquery, templates, function, plugins, scope

I am using the jQuery template plugin and I am calling the plugin from within a class.

In the example titled 
Example: Using the options parameter of the {{tmpl}} tag to provide a showLanguage method.

On the following page
http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl

They use an example like this:

```
   $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies, {
        languageOptions: {
            showLanguage: function showLanguage( name ) {
                return name.toUpperCase();
            }
        }
   }).appendTo( "#movieList" );


<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <tr>
        <td>${Name}</td>
        <td>{{tmpl(Languages.results, $item.languageOptions) "#languageTemplate"}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="languageTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <em>${$item.showLanguage(Name)} </em>
</script>
```

They pass through to the languageTemplate $item.languageOptions to access the showLanguage function.

My question is, how can I pass through functions that can be used in any of the templates, including templates that are being included by other templates, without the need to place functions in the global scope?

I know I can put the functions into their own namespace and then just access them that way but I would like to access functions from within the class.

If I exclude the showLanguage property in the above example and just pass in the showLanguage function on its own then the function is available to the first template but any other templates that access it have no reference to it and I don't want to be passing it around the place like they do in their example as it just seems messy to me.

Hopefully somebody can give me a nice solution.

Cheers,

Tim